# How to awk through multiple files?

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I have hundreds of `.dat` file with data in side and I want to awk them with the command

```
awk 'NR % 513 == 99' data.0003.127.dat > data.0003.127.Ma.dat
```

I tried to write a script file like

```
for i in {1 ... 9}; do
i=i*3
datafile = sprintf("data.%04d.127.dat",i)
outfile = sprintf("data.%04d.127.Ma.dat",i)
 awk 'NR % 513 == 99' datafile > outfile
done
```

I only need `0003` `0006` `0009` ... files, but the above script doesn't work fine. The error says

```
bash: ./Ma_awk.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: ./Ma_awk.sh: line 3: `datafile = sprintf("data.%04d.127.dat",i)'
```

What shall I do next? I use ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: multiple issues: don't use spaces around variable assignments, i.e. remove spaces before and after `=`. Also when you reference a variable in `bash` you have to use the `$` sign i.e. `"$datafile"` Note that when dealing with filenames it is wise to use double quotes. Then `sprintf` does not exist in `bash` use `printf` instead. `datafile=$(printf "%04d" $i)

Comment: Arithmetic needs to be done with `((i=i*3))` or some equivalent notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash (since v4) you can write a sequence expression with an increment:

```
$ echo {3..27..3}
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27
```

You can also include leading zeros, which will be preserved:

```
$ echo {0003..0027..3}
0003 0006 0009 0012 0015 0018 0021 0024 0027
```

So you could use the following:

```
for i in {0003..0027..3}; do
  awk 'NR % 513 == 99' "data.$i.127.dat" > "data.$i.127.Ma.dat"
done
```

Comment: @etan: true but OP claims to have Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code, simply because they are `bash` syntax errors.

1. Don't use spaces around variable assignment
2. Brace expension looks like `{1..9}`
3. Capturing stdout into a variable is done through `=$()` notation
4. Reference variables with the dollar sign `$`
5. Especially for filenames use double quotes `"` to ensure that the argument is considered as one

Now I have not considered the actual validity of your awk program but fixing the bash syntax errors would look something like the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..9}; do
    datafile=$(printf "data.%04d.127.dat" $i)
    outfile=$(printf "data.%04d.127.Ma.dat" $i)
    awk 'NR % 513 == 99' "$datafile" > "$outfile"
done
```

This does not take care of the correct iteration bounds with an increment of three, but since you have not specified an upper bound I will leave that as an exercise to you

Comment: I think it's `for i in {3..27..3}`

Comment: You are right, but he did not specify an upper bound and that was the last thing that was wrong with his script

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with the script, but you didn't pick the upper bound `9` out of thin air; it was there. I merely meant that you left out the attempt to multiply i by 3.